# How did the Omaha Gambit get its name?

Tags: opening, history, terminology, vienna-game

I was recently playing the Vienna Gambit as white on chess.com and was surprised to see a variation called the "Omaha gambit."

```
[Title "Vienna Game: Omaha Gambit"]
[StartPly "5"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 2. Nc3 d6 3. f4
```

I'm from Omaha,NE, so I was pleased to see my hometown represented, but I can't for the life of me think of any reason the gambit should be so named. Omaha is not known for a lively chess scene, has no grandmasters I'm aware of, and other meanings of Omaha (the Native tribe the town is named for and Peyton Manning's signal call) seem even less relevant.

How did the gambit get its name?

Comment: Maybe it's Warren Buffet's favorite opening?  I would like to know too!